# Eclipse java refactoring to change private method to public method

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

I forgot to add the public access modifier to my abstract methods of a super class - I'm assuming that the quickest way to fix this would be through some refactoring-type-thing but I can't figure out how.

My question is thus then:
Does Eclipse have a way to change the access modifier of a method such that classes that implement it will be affected? And how do I use it if it exists?

Thank you!

Comment: Simple and fast answer, no it doesn't at least AFAIK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the method `refactor -> change method signiture` change access modifier to public. I suggest doing this on the parent class method.

You can also open this config `alt + shift + c` keys if you are using default keys.

As a side note, when you dont specify any access modifier it will be package friendly. Also abstract methods can not be private.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for making my life easier! On the side note: I was made aware of 'package private' from my earlier googling before asking this question, but no, I needed to access the methods from another package. Still, I guess it's good to mention if anyone else finds this question and that information is helpful to them.